# TextWatcher's AfterTextChanged reacts on each key pressed?

Tags: android

I have an edit text view and I want to do some validation immediately after the user has stopped writing in the field and gone to the next one, so I decided that using AfterTextChanged would be a logical thing to do.

The problem is, AfterTextChanged runs the code I've written within the paretheses after each keystroke.

```
etUserPasswordSignupPage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //do some validation and then TOAST 
            }
        });
```

And the Toast shows multiple times, while Im typing :(
How can I make it wait while the user has stopped typing and gone to another field, or Done and then run the code for "afterTextChanged"?

EDIT:

Here is what happened after implementing the setOnEditorActionListener

```
09-26 17:15:36.275: E/AndroidRuntime(2102): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 17:15:36.275: E/AndroidRuntime(2102): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 17:15:36.275: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at net.shiftinpower.activities.Signup$4.onEditorAction(Signup.java:154)
09-26 17:15:36.275: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at android.widget.TextView.onEditorAction(TextView.java:3377)
09-26 17:15:36.275: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.performEditorAction(EditableInputConnection.java:83)
09-26 17:15:36.275: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:301)
09-26 17:15:36.275: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:79)
```

and here is my real code:

```
etUserPasswordAgainSignupPage.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
         if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            userPasswordAgain = etUserPasswordAgainSignupPage.getText().toString();

            if (userPasswordAgain.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(net.asdqwe.activities.Signup.this, configurationz.ERROR_MESSAGES_SIGNUP_FIELD_NOT_FILLED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                passwordAgainIsOk = true;
                Log.d("kylie", "pass again is ok");
            }

            if (!(userPassword.equals(userPasswordAgain))) {
                Toast.makeText(net.asdqwe.activities.Signup.this, configurationz.ERROR_MESSAGES_SIGNUP_PASSWORDS_DO_NOT_MATCH, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                passwordsMatch = false;
            } else {
                passwordsMatch = true;
                Log.d("kylie", "passwords match");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Use InputFilter to validate rather addTextChangedListener()

Comment: what you want to validate exactly

Comment: Since you're trying to validate after they move to the next input field, have you tried using an `OnFocusChangeListener` instead of `TextChangedListener`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code.... this code will trigger the onFocusChangeListener() immediately as EditText losses focus

```
   EditText et = new EditText(this); 
   //or
   EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
   et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!hasFocus){
                //Validate the string entered in EditText
            }
        }
    });

     OR 

     et.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                 //Do your validation thing here
            }
            return false; 
        }
    });
```

Comment: I cant take the focus off the last field before I submit, so the code never runs for it. How do I do that? @Kailash Ahirwar

Comment: for last EditText onFocusChangeListener will run when you will click on Submit button..but the problem here is that we don't know whether user completed typing or not??

Comment: I've updated my answer with what happened now @Kailash Ahirwar

Comment: use actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE instead of event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER in if condition...@J.Kowalski

Comment: The core of it: If EditText has focus or `IsInEditMode`, consider the change, otherwise discard it.